# Move files with date in file name to directories

Tags: shell-script, scripting, rhel

Need help sorting files by date within name with a script I can set in my cronjobs. The string I am trying to extract and make directories is the *YYYYMMDDHHMMSS*, this is present in all file names.

```
# ls
AB.CDEFGHIJ0KLM_NO_1234P5678_QR_9012_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_345678_ETH2_Testing-run_0.msg
```

i.e.  ABC.DVCSR1234_20191101120130_BLAH_97.msg
From

```
/home/user/files/AB.CDEFGHIJ0KLM_NO_1234P5678_QR_9012_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_345678_ETH2_Testing-run_0.msg
```

To

```
/home/user/files/2019/11/01/AB.CDEFGHIJ0KLM_NO_1234P5678_QR_9012_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_345678_ETH2_Testing-run_0.msg
```

I have thousands of these I need to reorganize to put in a file structure.

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of adding comments. Also, search a bit, this question has been asked very recently in either U&L or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky approach.  Usual disclaimer about parsing ls being bad, spaces in filenames breaking stuff, etc etc.

Create the folders.  Assumes all months have 31 days !

```
mkdir -p {2017..2019}/{01..12}/{01..31}
```

Get a preview of what it plans to do

```
ls ABC* | awk -F_ '{ print "mv",$0,substr($2,0,4)"/"substr($2,5,2)"/"substr($2,7,2)"/"$0}'
```

Run it for real, same command as above but with `| sh` tagged on

```
ls ABC* | awk -F_ '{ print "mv",$0,substr($2,0,4)"/"substr($2,5,2)"/"substr($2,7,2)"/"$0}' | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the files to move contain the pattern `_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/files
for file in *.msg; do
  date=$(printf "$file" | sed -nE 's/.*_([0-9]{4})([01][0-9])([0-3][0-9])[0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9][0-6][0-9]_.*/\1\/\2\/\3/p')
  if [ -n "$date" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$date" && mv "$file" "$date"
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Completely organized all files. Than you very much. What about the date= line would be different if you had files that just had YYYYMMDD?

Comment: With a `_YYYYMMDD_` pattern, you need to remove `[0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9][0-6][0-9]` from the regex. Right now it's just used to make the matching more secure (since there are other strings with digits).

Answer (score 1):

I have come to this using `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.msg" -exec bash -c 'DIRS=$(echo ${0} | cut -d'_' -f2); mkdir -p "${DIRS:0:4}/${DIRS:5:2}/${DIRS:7:2}"; mv "${0}" "${DIRS:0:4}/${DIRS:5:2}/${DIRS:7:2}"' {} \;
```